# Can/could vs. may/might (expressing typical occurrences)

Tags: word-usage, modal-verbs, formality

The following parts are taken from PEU:<sup>1</sup>

> **122.2  common or typical**
>
> We often use *can* to say what is common or typical.
>
> > Scotland can be very warm in September.
> >
> > Ann can really get on your nerves sometimes.
>
> **345.2 'general' possibility: *can/could*,  not *may/might***
>
> We normally use *can/could* to say that things are possible in general: 
>   people are able to do them, the situation makes them possible, or there is 
>   nothing to stop them. *May/might* are not used in this way.
>
> > These roses can grow anywhere.  (NOT  ••• These roses may grow anywhere.)
> >
> > Can gases freeze?  (NOT  ••• May gases freeze?)
> >
> > In those days, everybody could find a job.  (NOT  ••• In those days, everybody might find a job.)
>
> **339.10  another use of *may/might*: typical occurrences**
>
> In scientific and academic language, *may* is  often used to talk about typical 
>   occurrences - things that can happen in certain situations.
>
> > A female crocodile may lay 30-40 eggs.
> >
> > The flowers may have five or six petals, pink or red in colour.
> >
> > Children of divorced parents may have difficulty with relationships.
>
> With this meaning, *might* can be used to talk about the past.
>
> > In those days, a man might be hanged for stealing a sheep.

These explanations made me puzzled. Since they can both relate to typical occurrences, is it possible to substitute *can/could* for *may/might* in PEU 339.10 if the context is not written in scientific and academic language?

<sup>1. PEU = Michael Swan's, *Practical English Usage*.</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word *typical* is, I think, ill-chosen here. What the writers are saying at 122.2 might be better expressed thus;

> We often use *can* to signify that an eventuality does occur—not always, not necessarily even usually, but from time to time.

At 339.10 there are really two different uses which should be distinguished:

> *May* is used, particularly in academic and scientific contexts, to signify that  an outcome is possible but not necessary:
>    *Children of divorced parents may have difficulty with relationships.*
>
> *May* is also used in academic and scientific contexts to describe a range within which possible outcomes lie:
>    *A female crocodile may lay 30-40 eggs.*
>    *The flowers may have five or six petals, pink or red in colour.*

Either of these *may* uses can be expressed with *can* in colloquial registers. Colloquial *can* has largely (but not entirely) replaced *may*.

And (as you doubtless know) these do not exhaust the possible uses of either *may* or *can*.

Comment: THX! Do the examples imply _30-40 eggs/5 or 6 petals_ is the upper range for _a female crocodile's eggs/the flowers_ and the normal range will be a little lower than that?

Comment: @ZhanlongZheng By default these mean a range of from 30 to 40 eggs and either five or six petals, either pink or red - no other quantities or colors. But the sad fact is you can never count on a writer being sufficiently explicit: these writers **may** mean "up to 30 or even 40" and "up to five or six". That however is a problem with the writers, not with the language.

Comment: So by default, do these examples themselves preclude the possibility of any outcomes outside of the given range?

Comment: @ZhanlongZheng That's what you'd expect it to mean: the female crocodile will not lay fewer than 30 or more than 40 eggs (if she lays any eggs at all - you may reasonable infer that the writer is speaking only of female crocodiles who have mated).

Comment: Looking back, I feel "In those days, a man might be hanged for stealing a sheep." a little bit odd. As you said, the word typical is ill-chosen here. So is the case with _might_, I suppose, right? But we don't use "might + infinitive" alone to suggest a possibility in the past except when using it in a reported clause. We should use "might pp" or "could pp" instead. What do you think? @StoneyB

Comment: @ZhanlongZheng No. 1) In that sentence, *might* is simply past-tense *may*: "A man might be hanged then, he may be imprisoned now." 2) *May* and *might* **require** a bare infinitive; I'm not sure what you mean by 'pp', but *might hanged* or *might hanging* are impossible.

Comment: Sorry, I just woke up. You told me that "He might go to China last month" is not correct. 'pp' stands for 'past participle'. 1. Is it because it's a different usage of 'might' here? 2. "In those days, a man might be hanged for stealing a sheep." The sentence alone means a typical occurance or an occasional one? @StoneyB

Comment: @ZhanlongZheng 1. I take it you are referring to [this](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/19214/32). I didn't say it was incorrect; I said it was correct in certain specific circumstances. 2) It means a *possible* occurrence, without specifying a frequency.

Comment: But the example I gave is not in a reported speech or narrated in a past tense. Why not "could have hanged" or "might have hanged" instead? Is it because it is about a general possibility?  @StoneyB

Comment: @ZhanlongZheng First, you need *been* in those; it's a passive. Second, with *been* those would be *irrealis* pasts. Bare *might be hanged* is the *realis* past. *He might be hanged* represents a past possibility for what lay in the thief's future, parallel to a present possibility *He may be imprisoned*, describing what lies, possibly, in the future of today's thief.

Comment: 1. I think "might have been hanged" can be interpreted as a realis past just like "may have been hanged". 2. And forget about the objective truth, can I backshift the other examples like this: in those days, A female crocodile might lay 30-40 eggs; The flowers might have five or six petals; children of divorced parents might have difficulty with relationships?  @StoneyB I think this is what I really wanted to ask. Plz help.

Comment: @ZhanlongZheng 1. Quite so; but if they are realis they're not pasts but past perfects: "It was possible that he had been hanged." 2. Yes, you can say all of those, though it would be unlikely with generic truths like these which are true at all times, not just in the past.

Comment: We have come a long way to get here. Your other comments above can easily be beaten by this single one, for I know them all the time. Thx a lot! @StoneyB

Comment: @StoneyB - As KinzleB said in his original question, "We often use can to say what is common or typical. For example 'Scotland can be very warm in September'. So in this example does it mean that it will surely be very warm in September ?

Comment: @iamRR No. *Can* does not predict that it **will** be very warm sometime in September. It merely says that you should not be surprised if it **is** very warm sometime in September.

Comment: @StoneyB - So you mean to say that usage of 'can' expresses uncertainty. Right ? So if that's the case then am I to understand that there are even some remote chances where it will not be 'very warm sometime in September' ?

Comment: @iamRR No. Turn it around: *can* expresses definite possibility. It's exactly like saying "iamRR can write English." I have no idea whether you  actually **will** write English at any time in the future; you may decide you hate English, or you may die tonight; but I'm certain that you are capable of speaking English, because I've seen you do it.

Comment: @StoneyB I'll have to stack another Q here. :) I have distilled what puzzled me most. Is this 'theoretical' *can* identical with the 'hypothetical' *could*? If I reworded the examples as "Ann *could* really get on your nerves sometimes.", "These roses *could* grow anywhere." or "*Could* gases freeze?", would they mean the same?

Comment: @KinzleB They might; or they might be conditional, with unspecified conditions; or they might be past tense.

Comment: @StoneyB So in your framework the 'hypothetical' *could* is not conditional? What would be the difference?

Comment: @StoneyB I think I can put it this way without using too much jargon: with *can*, it implies past occurrences and potential future ones; with *could*, it doesn't imply or suggest past occurrences but future possibility. Am I right? BTW, let's not be concerned about the past tense use of "could " here. The examples are all set in the present tense narrative.

Comment: @KinzleB "It could get cold" asserts the possibility of future events; it does **not** implicate the actuality of past events. "It can get cold" also asserts the possibility of future events, and it implicates (but does not entail) the actuality of past events.

Answer (score 0):

The nuance of *may* and *can* is easy to understand but when it's about asking a question. When these verbs form a sentence (and not a question) they serve differently.

If I apply the general rule to **this particular question**, *can* talks about the *capability* of someone/something whereas *may* talks about the things that happen *naturally*. This having said, in the latter case, the subject is *not active*, *has not put their efforts.*

> A female crocodile **can** lay 30-40 eggs - *shows her capacity* 
>   A female crocodile **may** lay 30-40 eggs - *shows natural occurrence, her capacity is not emphasized*

Since scientific and academic research is more based on *natural occurrences* the book is suggesting using *may* over *can* which might refer to someone's capability or efforts to have that thing - This is my opinion.

I addressed your major concerned about replacing/interchanging *can* and *may* for that section. However, I guess rest is clear as it is.

[Good read about *may* and *can* is here.](http://data.grammarbook.com/blog/definitions/can-v-may/)